# How do i access fabric ca server REST API

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am able to interact with CA via fabric ca client of node SDK, But I can't access REST server, Can anybody provide me a getting started guide with CA API?  This is my docker compose file

```
ca:
image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
environment:
  - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.peers.test.com-cert.pem
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/CA_PRIVATE_KEY
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.peers.test.com-cert.pem
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/CA_PRIVATE_KEY
ports:
  - "7054:7054"
command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.peers.test.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/CA_PRIVATE_KEY -b admin:adminpw -d'
volumes:
  - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/peers.test.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
container_name: ca
networks:
  - test
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the swagger doc on the Fabric CA Github Repo (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/blob/release-1.3/swagger/swagger-fabric-ca.json)? This defines all the APIs that are available on the CA.

Comment: I have seen that but was not able to make any successful calls

Comment: Thanks Saad. I wasn't aware of this as I've not seen it mentioned in any of the other documentation.

Comment: @Saad: Do you have any code samples of REST API Integration?

Answer (score 0):

There is no documentation for direct access to the REST API (except for the swagger docs mentioned by Saad - which only documents the individual API calls, not how to use them). The API can be accessed either via the Node SDK, or the fabric-ca-server CLI.

Please see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664791/connecting-to-a-hyperledger-fabric-ca-server-using-an-endpoint-device) for more details.

Comment: Then why they have provided a REST API if it can't be accessed?

Comment: I'm not saying it can't be accessed, it's just not well documented. Is there a particular reason you can't use either of the existing methods?

Comment: with fabric ca client the keys are stored in a directory, right? and I have heard the libraries are not meant for production

Comment: That's right. The Node SDK client library stores all cryptographic artefacts in a local keystore. I'm surprised by your comment about the SDK not being production-ready. Where did you hear this?

Comment: I did not say that SDK is not ready for production, What I heard is it's for development, Especially fabric-ca-client library

Comment: By definition, and SDK is for development. That's why it's called a Software Development Kit!

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger normal REST call by browser or postman or curl etc.. based on swagger doc [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/blob/release-1.4/swagger/swagger-fabric-ca.json)

Port is **7054** and make sure you ignore the certificate error if you are using localhost as host name - like this:

> https://localhost:7054/api/v1/cainfo