# Connecting to a Hyperledger Fabric CA-Server using an endpoint device

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I have setup a Hyperledger Fabric CA-Server on an Ubuntu machine. I have enrolled an admin and also tried enrolling a few users. It worked perfectly fine.

I now want to register a few users through a Windows machine (Client) by sending requests to the validator machine.

- How do I proceed for this?
- What are the prerequisites to be installed in the client machine?
- How do I make use of the APIs of the Fabric network? Currently, it says, `'Listening on http://0.0.0.0:7054'`. Should the Firewall be disabled?

Comment: By "validator", do you mean orderer? It would help if you could describe your network topology. If you only have an orderer, then all you can do is administer the network. To add transactions to the ledger, you need at least one peer.

Comment: I am sorry. I meant CA Server. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods for managing users from a client machine, as follows:

- **The fabric-ca-client CLI** - documentation [here](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/users-guide.html?highlight=fabric-ca-client#fabric-ca-client). The compiled binary can be downloaded from the Hyperledger Nexus Repository [here](https://nexus.hyperledger.org/content/repositories/releases/org/hyperledger/fabric-ca/hyperledger-fabric-ca/).
- **The FabricCAClient class in the Hyperledger Fabric Node SDK** - documentation [here](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/FabricCAClient.html). Sample code can also be found [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.3/fabcar/registerUser.js) in the fabric-samples repository. Prerequisites and setup instructions [here](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-app-dev-env-setup.html).

Both of these methods use the Fabric CA API to communicate with the Fabric CA server.